# Make a computed property based on a mapped computed property on vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I need to use the value of the mapped state to generate another computed property.

```
computed: {
    ...mapState({
      items: (state) => state.items.items,
    }),
    isFood:  this.items.find(
          (item) => item.category == "Food"
        ) !== undefined
  },
```

when I try to run this, I get the error of `Cannot read property 'items' of undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to call `this.items.find` at *declaration time* of `isFood` - this wouldn't exist yet. Make it a function:

```
isFood() {
  return this.items.some((item) => item.category === "Food");
},
```

I also changed your function to use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) so that it won't bother looping through the rest of the items array when it finds a food.